# How to connect to your Prod/Dev database using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I’ve been using `phpMyAdmin` on my `local` environment for quit a while now. 
It comes with WAMP Server. I really like it. I was wondering if it’s possible to connect my dev/prod servers with it too.

As of now, I've using `MySQL WorkBench` for quite awhile now. I don't really like it that much.

If anyone have any experience with that, I hope you don’t mind give me some advice/suggestion to go above this.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a set of php scripts, nothing more

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin to connect to a remote mysql server - have you tried RTFM? :-)

Comment: I'm new, that's why I didn't know all of this. "Every artist was first an amateur." - right ? Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Dagon : so it means we can right ?

Comment: it means, i dont really understand what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin can connect to multiple servers by setting individual server connection details in `config.inc.php`.  You need To set $cfg['Servers'][$i] arrays for each server.  See the phpMyAdmin wiki for details: https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Multiserver (which is where the example below is from)

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret']='multiServerExample70518';
//any string of your choice (max. 46 characters)
$i = 0;  

$i++; // server 1 :
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; // needed for pma 2.x
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']   = 'no1'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
// more options for #1 ...

$i++; // server 2 :
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']   = 'no2'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'remote.host.addr';//or ip:'10.9.8.1'
// this server must allow remote clients, e.g., host 10.9.8.%
// not only in mysql.host but also in the startup configuration
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
// more options for #2 ... 

// end of server sections
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 0; // to choose the server on startup
```

Make sure to fully understand what you are doing and how you are connecting, you don't want to open access to your database to the outside world just to use phpMyAdmin.