# How can I host two "phpmyadmin" with different mysql versions?

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have installed two (MySQL)s versions 8.0.26(accessed via 3306) and 5.6(In a docker container but accessed locally via port 3310).

I have PHPMyAdmin for 8.0.26 installed and served by Nginx. But now I need to install the one for MySQL 5.7, I tried duplicating the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and modified

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
```

in `config.inc.php` and serve it using nginx  but it loads a blank page with `Failed to load resources error`

[image]

What could be the issue? or what's the best way to install multiple PHPMyAdmins on one computer?

Comment: You can manage multiple mysql instances from a single phpmyadmin instance.

Comment: How is this done?

Comment: If you read the phpMyAdmin Docs you can create multiple servers in the `config.inc.php` file

Comment: I tried using the settings in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413995/how-to-connect-to-your-prod-dev-database-using-phpmyadmin. The UI changed and now I can select different versions, but then they all pick the default port